# create button to add new line with today date and blank other fields

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, google-sheets-macros

I am trying to create a button (position should be fixed, so the button stays visible even when I scroll down sheet). I was able to draw it but now I stuck in the step of setting button up for this:

- After clicking on the button, it should add a new line (as line 16). In date fields, I would like to get prefilled today's date. Other fields should be blank.
- Line 15 is older line with inserted and chosen data from the dropdown list and date field.

[image]

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer by myself:

```
// global 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function my(){       
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = sh.getLastRow(), mylastrow=lRow + 1; 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A'+mylastrow).setValue('');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B'+mylastrow).setValue(new Date());
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C'+mylastrow).setValue('0');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D'+mylastrow).setValue('');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E'+mylastrow).setValue(new Date());
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F'+mylastrow).setValue('');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G'+mylastrow).setValue('');
}
```